# Relations involving Stirling numbers of second kind

Tags: stirling-numbers, laplace-transform

While inverting a Laplace transform using Post's inversion formula I found the following expression:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n S^n_k \ x^k(\alpha)_k
$$
where $S^n_k$ is a Stirling number of second kind and $(\alpha)_k$ is a Pochhammer symbol. This formula seems a mixture of the definition of these Stirling numbers and that of Touchard polynomials.

I tried without success to find an explicit expression for it. Does it exists? Or at least, is there an assymptotical expansion that for $n$ going to infinity?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you want to use generating functions here? 
The sum in question should be representable as a n-th coefficient in some generating function. For $S^n_k$ some generating functions are known (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheSecondKind.html, especially (14)-(16)). Pochhammers can arise from some operation on GF's (see Wilf's Generatingfunctionology)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f_n$ denote your expression. Using the well-known formula $\sum_n S_k^n\frac{t^n}{n!}
=\frac{1}{k!}(e^t-1)^k$, we get the generating function
   $$ \sum_{n\geq 0}f_n\frac{t^n}{n!} = (1-x(e^t-1))^{-\alpha}. $$
This generating function suggests that there will be no simpler expression for $f_n$ than its definition.

Comment: I was thinking about falling Pochhammer symbols so that changes the answer to $(1+x(e^t-1))^\alpha$, but that helps already. Thank you! 